# Storing information in active directory and using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am developing a ASP.Net website (Multibranch access and Multiuser Access) based on windows authentication. In this site, i require to manage access to the site based on the branch of logged in user (user automatically logged-in, as Windows Authentication is used.)

As i am not saving user details in my application database, and all user details are at Active Directory, How can i implement branch based login to the site.
Basically, what I need is that the administrator must be able to create user and assign branch to them so when user login, then based on their branch assigned, they automatically redirected to their branch page. Also user can access their own branch data while Administrator can access all branches data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to either keep track of the AD users (use their `objectGUID` as the key) in an external database, or extend the AD schema to include a `yourCorpBranchId` attribute you can go off of.